# Angular momentum vectors

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, vectors, torque

Hi I am trying to learn the concepts of angular momentum but I don't understand why in the formula for torque the radius from the line of action of the force is regarded as a vector surely distance is only a scalar so why is the cross product used?

Comment: actually that is not distance it is the position vector for the point of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\bf \tau = r \times F }$$
Here "**r**" is actually the position vector(also called radius vector) i.e. the vector from the axis of rotation to where the force is applied.
[image]

Its magnitude actually does equal the distance from the axis, but it's still a vector(having both magnitude and direction, as shown in the figure).

Comment: Thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 3):

That is not distance, It is position vector.

There is no concept that for a vector quantity always a cross product of two vectors is taken.
In physics some quantities are even given direction so that you can take their cross product.
Cross product is a tool not a property.